# Asp.net MVC Ajax Button to retrieve a single data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-ajax

I want to retrieve the first record in my database when ever I click the Ajax button, right now whenever I click my button it returns a List of my Record, I just want to retrieve the first record then when I click it again, returns the second record, is that even possible?

Here is my Ajax button :

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "BtnNext", null@*new { count = count + 1}*@, new AjaxOptions
                   {
                   HttpMethod = "GET",
                   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                   UpdateTargetId = "current"
                   }, new { @class = "Middle-next dim btn btn-large-dim", @id = "Link1"})
```

Here is the controller for the Ajax button :

```
    public PartialViewResult BtnNext()
    {
        var model = db.Queues.OrderBy(x => x.QueueNumber);
        return PartialView("_queuenumber", model);
    }
```

Thankyou so much, newbie <<

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var model = db.Queues.ToList().OrderBy(x => x.QueueNumber).Take(1);
```

Comment: I want when i click the button again it will render the second record, click then render the third record and so on.

Comment: for that you need to send the current `queueid` probably as a parameter to the controller method so that you could create the list again and use `where` clause to exclude that `queueid`. Or else you could also use the `.Skip()` as well if you have the no of elements already displayed. `Skip()` is to be used just before `Take()` in your statement. Choice is upto you.